# How can I make this menu have multiple depths?

Tags: gui-design, web-app, interface

This is for a bookmarking application that should be easy for anyone to use. Right now it is very simple and has only tags.

But I want to be able to import bookmarks.  And in most cases bookmarks can be stored in a folder that is in another folder, which can be stored in another folder etc.  I.E. there are multiple depths.

Here is my simple solution:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the following layout which allows you to :

1. **Select Tags:** ability to add "N" number of tags, autocomplete to help select existing tags from the available list.
2. **Bookmark Location:** ability to navigate "N" level tree structure and select necessary level (you may exclude a list of actual bookmarks from the list and only display folders). Also provide the ability to create new folders if one does not exist.
3. **Location:** (or a different label). As the user to provide the URL + Title. CTA label should be clear as well.

[image: bookmark solution proposed wireframe]

Comment: I just built it with this tool: https://balsamiq.com

Comment: Nice stuff ... well organized.  I'll go ahead and mark it as an answer.